# compiling in angular7 image path is taking wrongly

Tags: angular

I have folder sturucture like below
`assets/css/img`.
In my css accessing the images in img folder  `../img/drop_down.png`  while compiling in Angular 7, but it is taking the path `assets/css/img/drop_down.png`. Can anybody tell where to change the configuration in Angular 7?

Thanks

Comment: What is your compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/assets/img/drop_down.png`, it is not good practice to make css dependent on asset relative path for static resources such as a dropdown item.

It makes life far easier when you refactor code & components.